# secondary indexing/sorting in a microservice with the entity details residing in another microservice

Tags: microservices, nosql

Let's say we have two microservices - one manages/stores users (ids and user details: name, email, etc) and another manages/stores user groups (list of user ids).

A group does not have any limit so potentially may contain millions of user ids.

Now the requirement for the group microservice is to fetch users in a group (say from position 0 and page size 10) **sorted** by last name (or email, or time registered, etc.)

So how is it done generally in microservice architecture?

1) Denormalize and index user details in the Groups store? Sounds like major pain in keeping the data in sync. Also does it break the whole concept?

2) Keep users and groups together in a single microservice? Is it a general approach when secondary indexing is involved? Again does it break the concept of separating concerns?

Comment: this might be more on topic at programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: what kind of questions do you expect under "microservice" tag? Wouldn't architecture questions belong here by definition?

Comment: my apologies. I just felt that a question that asks about how a programming goal is accomplished would be closer to the reason that programmers SE was founded, as your question does not describe a specific problem you are having.

Comment: Doesn't sound like your question really involves indexing. It doesn't discuss how search is affected on the database level. The indexing might throw people off if you want an architectural answer.

Comment: Well if you want something sorted by other than a primary key (user id), doesn't it automatically imply a need in a some sort of secondary indexing?

Comment: It does but it wouldn't have anything to do with microservices. Would this be an indexing question or a microservices question? From the two findings you listed, it sounds like its a microservice related question. Where does the secondary indexing come into play? The two are kind of independent of each other.

Comment: Right, if it was indeed a single backend application/service, there would not be a problem in the first place (option 2 in my question).  Perhaps you did not read fully my question or I was not clear...

Comment: I could be confused; secondary indexing is independent to whether there should be two services or a single service so it feels out of place when it becomes to being a concern on deciding whether to have two services or a single service. In your scenario what are the responsibilities of the users service? Groups service sounds like it would be responsible for enabling searching users by groups but what about the users service?

Comment: User service is is responsible for user crud ops. Group service is for creating groups, adding/removing users. In our naive original design it does not poses user details only referencing users by guid. Now imagine UI screen where we would like to list users in a group page by page. For that we would just call group service endpoint and get a page of user ids, then pass these ids to the user service to get user details (could be a batch call as number of ids on a page is reasonably small), the finally display the items in UI.

Comment: So far so good, except that the users will be listed in a random alphabetical order... So is the problem becoming more apparent now? How are you going to fix the sort problem?